# Why is my sin function in C returning nan instead of a double value?

Tags: c, function, variables, math

I am trying to make a sin function from scratch in C, but it is constantly returning NaN when I run it.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double factorial(in){
    if(in == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    return in * factorial(in - 1);
}

double sine(double doub) {
    double sum = 0;
    int times = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
        int odd = 2*i + 1;
        double add = pow(doub, odd) / factorial(odd);
        switch(i%2){
            case 0:
                sum += add;
                break;
            default:
                sum -= add;
                break;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    printf("%lf\n", sine(55));
}
```

This is my script, I am using the McLaurin Series expansion of sin to work this out, why is it not returning the expected value?

Comment: 55 radians is far from 0. That wouldn't be enough terms to get good convergence there and roundoff error would be a major issue with things like `pow(55,101)`. Were you trying to do 55 degrees? Use fewer terms and evaluate at points closer to 0.

Comment: `factorial(odd)` goes to `inf` in the last few iterations of the loop, as the value exceeds the range of the `double` type.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki I doubt that. Rather, it invokes undefined behavior because of `int` overflow.

Comment: `double factorial(in)` There should be a parameter type specified.

Comment: Not your issue, but In general, this approach looks really inefficient. In each iteration of that loop, `odd` gets increments by `1`. The differenct in `add` could be calculated using the previous one `* -1 * (doub*doub) / (odd*(odd-1))`. There is no need to calculate both parts again and again and again ....

Comment: @Nelfeal `odd` goes up to `199`, and `199!` has 373 digits in decimal, which is way beyond the max value of `double`, so it sure will cause problems.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki My mistake, somehow I had in mind that the multiplication would get done as `int` but since `factorial` *returns* a `double`, there is no `int` overflow, just a `double` "overflow" to inf.

Comment: As @Gerhardh: you can avoid huge factorials by working with a 'term'. At each iteration you multiply *term* by *x* and divide it by *n*.

Comment: My previous comment should be "`odd` get incremented by 2"

Answer (score 1):

During the last iteration of the loop, `odd = 2*99+1 = 199`. So in this line:

```
double add = pow(doub, odd) / factorial(odd);
```

both `pow(doub, odd)` and `factorial(odd)` are over the maximum finite value that a `double` can hold, and so you end up with `+inf / +inf`, which is `NaN`. This `NaN` propagates to `sum` and that's what gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

Code iterated too many times and eventually calculates `inf / inf`, which is `NAN`. [@Nelfeal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74518303/2410359)

**Range reduction:**  For tight code `sine()`, perform range reduction first.  Simplistic `fmod()` useful for `|x| < ~1,000`.  Beyond that, more advance techniques needed.  This reduces the need for many terms in the series.

**Stop when terms are small:** Once the additional terms are so small, stop iterating.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MY_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

double sine(double x) {
  // Omit this step if `x < 2*PI` expected.
  x = fmod(x, 2 * MY_PI);  // floating-point remainder of x/y.

  double xx = x*x;
  double term = 1.0;
  double sum = 0.0;
  unsigned n = 1;
  do {
    sum += term;
    term *= -xx / ((n + 1) * (n + 2));
    n += 2;
  } while (fabs(term) > DBL_EPSILON / 2);
  return sum * x;
}
```

Additional improvements possible.